# Magento Magmi how to add custom option color image

Tags: php, magento

I am using magmi for product and product custom option import

For custom option I am trying create size and color its created successfully through below CSV

```
sku,name,description,price,Size:drop_down:1,Color:drop_down:1
E90451,T-Shirt,A T-Shirt,5,Small|Medium|Large,red|green
```

Now, my issue is I need color with image like for red (red color image)  and for green(green color image), and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: did you found solution ? can you please tell what you did to fix the issue.....